# Mandatory Profile Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bit

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, user-profiles, windows-10-v1607

In my LAB environment all my computers run mandatory profile since windows 7 and i deploy the configuration using GP, recently when i switched to windows 10 mandatory profile was kind of buggy, since the anniversary update ( 1607 ) i was able to create a mandatory profile through OOB with sysprep altho it works its still kind of hard to manage for example :

On the creation of the profile, some settings requires restart and obviously when OOB and in sysprep i could not restart the machine otherwise everything will be lost, this means everytime the user logs in IE or Edge starts up with the microsoft welcome site and stuffs , and i couldn't change the default app extensions and many other stuffs .

I cannot edit the profile for example changing the extenstion of NTuser from MAN to DAT making changes and reverting them back, it will result in a corrupt / temporary profile .

I have tried to follow many articles on the web including the Technet blog and i wasnt being able to acheive a proper profile so if anyone could hand me a tip , solution , workaround or anything to create a new mandatory profile for windows 10 without oob or sysprep that can help it would be much much apreciated.

My machines run Windows 10 64bit enterprise edition ( 1607 build ) with a windows server 2012r2 DC .

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Its not unusual to require a user, to log into their account then logout, in order to apply group policy to the machine though.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Edit your question to clarify the problem you face and indicate exactly what your question is.  I was just pointing, the description you did provided, is not that unsual, when a user logs into a machine on domain they have to logout then back in order for the group policy to be applied to the machine.

Comment: it is now edited

Comment: Anyone so far has figured something ?